# ConTeXt: text overlapping title in serried enumeration

Tags: context

Consider the following piece of code

```tex
\defineenumeration[axiom]
                    [prefix=yes,
                    alternative=serried,
                    text=Axiom,
                    right={.~},
                    title=yes,
                    titlestyle={\tf},
                    titleleft={(},
                    titleright={)},
                    style={\it}]

\startTEXpage
\startaxiom[title={Incidence Axiom I}]
  For every pair of distinct points $P$ and $Q$ there is exactly one line $l$ such that $P$ and $Q$ lie on $l$.
\stopaxiom
\stopTEXpage
```

This piece of code produces a simple enumeration for axioms. Now, when using it the title is overlapped by the text content of the axiom, just like so:

[image]

How can I avoid that behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `width=fit`.

```
\defineenumeration
  [axiom]
  [prefix=yes,
  alternative=serried,
  text=Axiom,
  right={.~},
  title=yes,
  titlestyle={\tf},
  titleleft={(},
  titleright={)},
  width=fit,
  style={\it}]

\startTEXpage[offset=1dk]
\startaxiom[title={Incidence Axiom I}]
  For every pair of distinct points $P$ and $Q$ there is exactly one line $l$ such that $P$ and $Q$ lie on $l$.
\stopaxiom
\stopTEXpage
```

[image: with with=fit]